# What was the official theoretical journal of the communist party of the USSR?

Tags: soviet-union, communism, socialism, journalism, theory

Like other ruling communist parties the propaganda organs of the USSR would have also published material covering theoretical topics relating to building socialism, communism, etc. These materials were likely assembled into a journal for distribution and so on.

I am having difficulty finding the name and other information regarding the publication. What would the details be?

Comment: The "Communist".

Comment: @MoisheKohan It ended publication in 1944, what was the successor journal?

Comment: it continued until the dissolution of the USSR. (The original name was "Большевик", until 1952, when the party changed its name.) https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kommunist&ved=2ahUKEwiD1qv8wubyAhUOHzQIHTbRBpMQFnoECCkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1FEo94R3WbFvbigGsuAnjm

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks, it seems like the official english translation had ended in 1944.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kommunist It is still published under different name: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get this question from the "unanswered" list:

The journal was called "Communist" ("Коммунист") between 1952-1991; earlier (1924-1952) it was published under the name "Bolshevik." See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kommunist).